# pry rescue exit program immediately when error occurs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I make my script has some buggy line intentionally,

And I expected the pry will stop by the buggy line, but it didn't.

```
% rescue rake test:sample                                                                                                    (git)-[develop]
rake aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `hi' for main:Object
/Users/lib/tasks/test.rake:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => test:sample
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

### Gem

```
pry (0.10.1)
pry-byebug (2.0.0)
pry-doc (0.6.0)
pry-rails (0.3.2)
pry-rescue (1.4.1)
pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.1)
```

### Rake file

```
desc "Import User."
# http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/18070048430/anonymizing-customer-company-and-location-data-using
namespace :import do
    task :orders => :environment do
      require_relative './parser_v1'
      require_relative './parser_20120709_20121030'
```

Comment: Could you provide test.rake code?

Comment: I think you are not loading rails env with => :environment clause on your rake task

Comment: Hi @emaxi  I added my partial rake file, thanks